# Cannot exit in CodeIgniter constructor

Tags: php, codeigniter, exit-code

I'm basically trying a session control. If the user is logged in, it's ok to move on. But if he's not logged in, then it will show a log-in screen and then die. However, when I use `die` or `exit` in the constructor, it does not show the log-in screen; it immediately dies. The code is as following:

```
private $username = null;
private $mongoid = null;
private $neoid = null;

public function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();

    // session to global
    $this->username = $this->session->userdata( 'username');
    $this->mongoid = $this->session->userdata( 'mongoid');
    $this->neoid = $this->session->userdata( 'neoid');

    // check if user is logged in
    if( $this->username == "" || empty( $this->username)){
        $this->load->view( 'access/login');
        die;
    }
}
```

It shows the log-in page if `die` is not written there, but with `die`, it does not show. Why do I want to use `die`? Because if I don't use, it moves on the index function and I don't want it to execute index function if the user is not logged in.

What is wrong here? What should I use to stop executing?

Comment: You need to show it to user using echo or something first.

Comment: what happens if you replace `die;` with: `echo $this->output->get_output(); exit;`

Comment: why are you building this yourself? Does CI not have an Authentication Bundle or something? In any case, you dont want to have that check in the User class, let alone in the constructor. It does not belong there but in an Authentication Service class.

Comment: Show what? The view page? Or anything?

Comment: John, thank you. It is solved. Can you please post it an answer, so I can mark as the right answer?

Comment: Gordon, I don't think there is. I mean there are some libraries written by out of CI team but not included in the CI core.

Comment: @gzg use `ion auth` or `tank auth`, they are almost perfect, they have great support and are widely used, no need to build a wheel

Comment: @Vlakarados, Tank Auth looks good but I'm not using SQL.

Comment: @gzg what are you using then?

Comment: Both MongoDB and Neo4J as databases. The info that session management requires is stored in MongoDB.

Comment: @Gordon CI does not have a built-in authentication library. Authentication libraries are very requirements-based, and that is their reasoning for not including one.

Comment: Hi @gzg, if any of below answers has solved your question please consider [accepting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) the best answer or adding your own solution. So, that it indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution.

Answer (score 1):

CodeIgniter does not instantly output the view when you load it with `$this->load->view();`, it puts the output of the view to the output buffer instead and after everything is loaded it flushes the whole output to the user. With that said, the problem you are seeing is that it buffers the output, then it dies without flushing it.

`die` is really bad and should not be used outside debugging, you should better use something like a variable switch. If it's only for the controllers scope, then you can make a

```
private $show_everything_else = true;
```

In the constructor:

```
if( $this->username == "" || empty( $this->username)){
    $this->load->view( 'access/login');
    $this->show_everything_else = false;
}
```

In any of the controller's methods:

```
if($this->show_everything_else) {
    // ...
}
```

In any case, this solution is a quick fix and there are much better possibilities how to do this, but all of them require a different approach.

Comment: Well, it's a good approach but I'd rather not using if-else statements constantly.

Comment: Then better make a library and move all the logic there, or at least a model.

Comment: and [dont do it in the constructor](http://misko.hevery.com/code-reviewers-guide/flaw-constructor-does-real-work/).

Answer (score 1):

You can have a method and call it in constructor:

```
function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->_is_logged_in();
}
```

and the method should look like this:

```
function _is_logged_in() {
    $is_logged_in = $this->session->userdata('is_logged_in');
    if (!isset($is_logged_in) || $is_logged_in != true) {
        redirect('login');
        die();
    }
}
```

And, of course, you should have controller for login, which can look like this:

```
<?php

class Login extends CI_Controller {

    function index() {
        $this->load->view('LOGIN-VIEW');
    }

    function validate() {
        $this->load->model('login_model');
        $data = $this->login_model->validate();

        if ($data != false) {
            $data['is_logged_in'] = true;
            $this->session->set_userdata($data);
            redirect('MAIN-CONTROLLER-AFTER-LOGIN');
        }
        else {
            $this->index();
        }
    }

    function logout() {
        $this->session->sess_destroy();
        $this->index();
    }

}
```

This what i posted, also preserve sessions in database.

Login model can be as primitive as this:

class Login_model extends CI_Model {

```
function validate() {


    $this->db->where('username', $this->input->post('username'));
    $this->db->where('password', md5($this->input->post('password')));
    $query = $this->db->get('users');

    if($query->num_rows == 1) {
        $data = $query->row_array();
             return $data;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The Controller class will automatically run the index() function. So, to make it work, you must return the index() if the login check in construct is failed. Here what you can do:

```
private $username = null;
private $mongoid = null;
private $neoid = null;
private $no_login = false;

public function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();

    // session to global
    $this->username = $this->session->userdata( 'username');
    $this->mongoid = $this->session->userdata( 'mongoid');
    $this->neoid = $this->session->userdata( 'neoid');

    // check if user is logged in
    if( $this->username == "" || empty( $this->username)){
        $this->load->view( 'access/login');
        $this->no_login = true;
    }
}

function index(){
    if($this->no_login) return;
    // another statement if login success.....
}
```